# Support for ordered lists in MDriven?

Tags: mdriven

I have seen a demo on how to use ordered lists in MDriven but I can not find it on the wiki? Is it deprecated or am I just looking in the wrong place? The need is to show an strictly ordered list, enabling the user to move items up and down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy - on the "many" end of the relation - set "Ordered" in the property inspector. Once that is done evolve will add a "_o" field in your db next to the foreign key.

Comment: Yes found it ! Thanx!